# Confusing about the output

Tags: oop, while-loop

I'm new to java programming. I just start to reading Head first java book. And I found this example on first chapter.

```
public class BeerSong {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int beerNum = 99;
        String word = "bottles";
        while (beerNum > 0)
        {
            if (beerNum == 1)
            {
                word = "bottle";
            }
            System.out.println(beerNum + " " + word + " of beer on the wall");
            System.out.println(beerNum + " " + word + " of beer");
            System.out.println("Take one down.");
            System.out.println("Pass it around.");
            beerNum = beerNum - 1;
            if (beerNum > 0)
            {
                System.out.println(beerNum +  " " + word + " of beer on the wall");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("No more bottles of beer on the wall");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I'm confused about the out put.

```
60 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
59 bottles of beer on the wall
59 bottles of beer on the wall
59 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
58 bottles of beer on the wall
58 bottles of beer on the wall
58 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
57 bottles of beer on the wall
57 bottles of beer on the wall
57 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
56 bottles of beer on the wall
56 bottles of beer on the wall
56 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
55 bottles of beer on the wall
55 bottles of beer on the wall
55 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
54 bottles of beer on the wall
54 bottles of beer on the wall
54 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
53 bottles of beer on the wall
53 bottles of beer on the wall
53 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
52 bottles of beer on the wall
52 bottles of beer on the wall
52 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
51 bottles of beer on the wall
51 bottles of beer on the wall
51 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
50 bottles of beer on the wall
50 bottles of beer on the wall
50 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
49 bottles of beer on the wall
49 bottles of beer on the wall
49 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
48 bottles of beer on the wall
48 bottles of beer on the wall
48 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
47 bottles of beer on the wall
47 bottles of beer on the wall
47 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
46 bottles of beer on the wall
46 bottles of beer on the wall
46 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
45 bottles of beer on the wall
45 bottles of beer on the wall
45 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
44 bottles of beer on the wall
44 bottles of beer on the wall
44 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
43 bottles of beer on the wall
43 bottles of beer on the wall
43 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
42 bottles of beer on the wall
42 bottles of beer on the wall
42 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
41 bottles of beer on the wall
41 bottles of beer on the wall
41 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
40 bottles of beer on the wall
40 bottles of beer on the wall
40 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
39 bottles of beer on the wall
39 bottles of beer on the wall
39 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
38 bottles of beer on the wall
38 bottles of beer on the wall
38 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
37 bottles of beer on the wall
37 bottles of beer on the wall
37 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
36 bottles of beer on the wall
36 bottles of beer on the wall
36 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
35 bottles of beer on the wall
35 bottles of beer on the wall
35 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
34 bottles of beer on the wall
34 bottles of beer on the wall
34 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
33 bottles of beer on the wall
33 bottles of beer on the wall
33 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
32 bottles of beer on the wall
32 bottles of beer on the wall
32 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
31 bottles of beer on the wall
31 bottles of beer on the wall
31 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
30 bottles of beer on the wall
30 bottles of beer on the wall
30 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
29 bottles of beer on the wall
29 bottles of beer on the wall
29 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
28 bottles of beer on the wall
28 bottles of beer on the wall
28 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
27 bottles of beer on the wall
27 bottles of beer on the wall
27 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
26 bottles of beer on the wall
26 bottles of beer on the wall
26 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
25 bottles of beer on the wall
25 bottles of beer on the wall
25 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
24 bottles of beer on the wall
24 bottles of beer on the wall
24 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
23 bottles of beer on the wall
23 bottles of beer on the wall
23 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
22 bottles of beer on the wall
22 bottles of beer on the wall
22 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
21 bottles of beer on the wall
21 bottles of beer on the wall
21 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
20 bottles of beer on the wall
20 bottles of beer on the wall
20 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
19 bottles of beer on the wall
19 bottles of beer on the wall
19 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
18 bottles of beer on the wall
18 bottles of beer on the wall
18 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
17 bottles of beer on the wall
17 bottles of beer on the wall
17 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
16 bottles of beer on the wall
16 bottles of beer on the wall
16 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
15 bottles of beer on the wall
15 bottles of beer on the wall
15 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
14 bottles of beer on the wall
14 bottles of beer on the wall
14 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
13 bottles of beer on the wall
13 bottles of beer on the wall
13 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
12 bottles of beer on the wall
12 bottles of beer on the wall
12 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
11 bottles of beer on the wall
11 bottles of beer on the wall
11 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
10 bottles of beer on the wall
10 bottles of beer on the wall
10 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
9 bottles of beer on the wall
9 bottles of beer on the wall
9 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
8 bottles of beer on the wall
8 bottles of beer on the wall
8 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
7 bottles of beer on the wall
7 bottles of beer on the wall
7 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
6 bottles of beer on the wall
6 bottles of beer on the wall
6 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
5 bottles of beer on the wall
5 bottles of beer on the wall
5 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
4 bottles of beer on the wall
4 bottles of beer on the wall
4 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
3 bottles of beer on the wall
3 bottles of beer on the wall
3 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
2 bottles of beer on the wall
2 bottles of beer on the wall
2 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
1 bottles of beer on the wall
1 bottle of beer on the wall
1 bottle of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
No more bottles of beer on the wall
Press any key to continue . . .
```

As I understand the code out put should be start with

```
99 bottles of beer
```

because `int beerNum = 99;`

Can anyone explain me why I'm getting above output start with

```
60 bottles of beer
```

Thanks in advance.
I would be so great full if someone explain me this.

Comment: The code above should in fact start with "99 bottles of beer." Are you sure you're running that exact code to get the "60 bottles of beer" output?

Comment: Yes I'm running the exact code @at.

Comment: If you're running on a unix system (or mac) trying piping that into head `java myapp | head` and see if you get the 99 bottles of beer.

Comment: Or maybe @LamaHaris, your output window/tab is limited in how many lines it displays or allows you to scroll back to. So it output 99 bottles, 98 bottles, etc. But that output got lost because of all the extra lines of output after.

Comment: try to change `while (beerNum > 0)` to `while (beerNum > 96)` to show only 3 rounds of beer on the wall. You should see 99 bottles, 98 bottles, 97 bottles.

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: I'm using Geany. @ErwinBolwidt

Comment: @LamaHaris Sorry not familiar with that. But like others have mentioned, you need to find out how to to set the console size / scrollback buffer / whatever they call that in Geany to at least 500 lines (100 bottles times 5 lines of output per bottle) to see all output. But if you run it on the console, you can pipe the output to `less` or `more`: `java -cp <classpath> BeerSong | less`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, output should begin with,

```
99 bottles of beer
```

There is nothing wrong in your code. As you said you used Geany as your IDE. Geany uses command line to show output. If you use eclipse or netbeans you'll get the proper output as you imagine.

**eclipse output -**

```
99 bottles of beer on the wall
99 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
98 bottles of beer on the wall
98 bottles of beer on the wall
98 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
97 bottles of beer on the wall
97 bottles of beer on the wall
97 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
96 bottles of beer on the wall
96 bottles of beer on the wall
96 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
95 bottles of beer on the wall
95 bottles of beer on the wall
95 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
94 bottles of beer on the wall
94 bottles of beer on the wall
94 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
93 bottles of beer on the wall
93 bottles of beer on the wall
93 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
92 bottles of beer on the wall
92 bottles of beer on the wall
92 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
91 bottles of beer on the wall
91 bottles of beer on the wall
91 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
90 bottles of beer on the wall
90 bottles of beer on the wall
90 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
89 bottles of beer on the wall
89 bottles of beer on the wall
89 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
88 bottles of beer on the wall
88 bottles of beer on the wall
88 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
87 bottles of beer on the wall
87 bottles of beer on the wall
87 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
86 bottles of beer on the wall
86 bottles of beer on the wall
86 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
85 bottles of beer on the wall
85 bottles of beer on the wall
85 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
84 bottles of beer on the wall
84 bottles of beer on the wall
84 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
83 bottles of beer on the wall
83 bottles of beer on the wall
83 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
82 bottles of beer on the wall
82 bottles of beer on the wall
82 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
81 bottles of beer on the wall
81 bottles of beer on the wall
81 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
80 bottles of beer on the wall
80 bottles of beer on the wall
80 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
79 bottles of beer on the wall
79 bottles of beer on the wall
79 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
78 bottles of beer on the wall
78 bottles of beer on the wall
78 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
77 bottles of beer on the wall
77 bottles of beer on the wall
77 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
76 bottles of beer on the wall
76 bottles of beer on the wall
76 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
75 bottles of beer on the wall
75 bottles of beer on the wall
75 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
74 bottles of beer on the wall
74 bottles of beer on the wall
74 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
73 bottles of beer on the wall
73 bottles of beer on the wall
73 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
72 bottles of beer on the wall
72 bottles of beer on the wall
72 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
71 bottles of beer on the wall
71 bottles of beer on the wall
71 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
70 bottles of beer on the wall
70 bottles of beer on the wall
70 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
69 bottles of beer on the wall
69 bottles of beer on the wall
69 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
68 bottles of beer on the wall
68 bottles of beer on the wall
68 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
67 bottles of beer on the wall
67 bottles of beer on the wall
67 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
66 bottles of beer on the wall
66 bottles of beer on the wall
66 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
65 bottles of beer on the wall
65 bottles of beer on the wall
65 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
64 bottles of beer on the wall
64 bottles of beer on the wall
64 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
63 bottles of beer on the wall
63 bottles of beer on the wall
63 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
62 bottles of beer on the wall
62 bottles of beer on the wall
62 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
61 bottles of beer on the wall
61 bottles of beer on the wall
61 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
60 bottles of beer on the wall
60 bottles of beer on the wall
60 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
59 bottles of beer on the wall
59 bottles of beer on the wall
59 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
58 bottles of beer on the wall
58 bottles of beer on the wall
58 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
57 bottles of beer on the wall
57 bottles of beer on the wall
57 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
56 bottles of beer on the wall
56 bottles of beer on the wall
56 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
55 bottles of beer on the wall
55 bottles of beer on the wall
55 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
54 bottles of beer on the wall
54 bottles of beer on the wall
54 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
53 bottles of beer on the wall
53 bottles of beer on the wall
53 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
52 bottles of beer on the wall
52 bottles of beer on the wall
52 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
51 bottles of beer on the wall
51 bottles of beer on the wall
51 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
50 bottles of beer on the wall
50 bottles of beer on the wall
50 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
49 bottles of beer on the wall
49 bottles of beer on the wall
49 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
48 bottles of beer on the wall
48 bottles of beer on the wall
48 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
47 bottles of beer on the wall
47 bottles of beer on the wall
47 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
46 bottles of beer on the wall
46 bottles of beer on the wall
46 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
45 bottles of beer on the wall
45 bottles of beer on the wall
45 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
44 bottles of beer on the wall
44 bottles of beer on the wall
44 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
43 bottles of beer on the wall
43 bottles of beer on the wall
43 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
42 bottles of beer on the wall
42 bottles of beer on the wall
42 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
41 bottles of beer on the wall
41 bottles of beer on the wall
41 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
40 bottles of beer on the wall
40 bottles of beer on the wall
40 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
39 bottles of beer on the wall
39 bottles of beer on the wall
39 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
38 bottles of beer on the wall
38 bottles of beer on the wall
38 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
37 bottles of beer on the wall
37 bottles of beer on the wall
37 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
36 bottles of beer on the wall
36 bottles of beer on the wall
36 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
35 bottles of beer on the wall
35 bottles of beer on the wall
35 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
34 bottles of beer on the wall
34 bottles of beer on the wall
34 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
33 bottles of beer on the wall
33 bottles of beer on the wall
33 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
32 bottles of beer on the wall
32 bottles of beer on the wall
32 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
31 bottles of beer on the wall
31 bottles of beer on the wall
31 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
30 bottles of beer on the wall
30 bottles of beer on the wall
30 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
29 bottles of beer on the wall
29 bottles of beer on the wall
29 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
28 bottles of beer on the wall
28 bottles of beer on the wall
28 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
27 bottles of beer on the wall
27 bottles of beer on the wall
27 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
26 bottles of beer on the wall
26 bottles of beer on the wall
26 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
25 bottles of beer on the wall
25 bottles of beer on the wall
25 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
24 bottles of beer on the wall
24 bottles of beer on the wall
24 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
23 bottles of beer on the wall
23 bottles of beer on the wall
23 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
22 bottles of beer on the wall
22 bottles of beer on the wall
22 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
21 bottles of beer on the wall
21 bottles of beer on the wall
21 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
20 bottles of beer on the wall
20 bottles of beer on the wall
20 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
19 bottles of beer on the wall
19 bottles of beer on the wall
19 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
18 bottles of beer on the wall
18 bottles of beer on the wall
18 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
17 bottles of beer on the wall
17 bottles of beer on the wall
17 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
16 bottles of beer on the wall
16 bottles of beer on the wall
16 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
15 bottles of beer on the wall
15 bottles of beer on the wall
15 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
14 bottles of beer on the wall
14 bottles of beer on the wall
14 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
13 bottles of beer on the wall
13 bottles of beer on the wall
13 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
12 bottles of beer on the wall
12 bottles of beer on the wall
12 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
11 bottles of beer on the wall
11 bottles of beer on the wall
11 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
10 bottles of beer on the wall
10 bottles of beer on the wall
10 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
9 bottles of beer on the wall
9 bottles of beer on the wall
9 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
8 bottles of beer on the wall
8 bottles of beer on the wall
8 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
7 bottles of beer on the wall
7 bottles of beer on the wall
7 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
6 bottles of beer on the wall
6 bottles of beer on the wall
6 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
5 bottles of beer on the wall
5 bottles of beer on the wall
5 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
4 bottles of beer on the wall
4 bottles of beer on the wall
4 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
3 bottles of beer on the wall
3 bottles of beer on the wall
3 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
2 bottles of beer on the wall
2 bottles of beer on the wall
2 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
1 bottles of beer on the wall
1 bottle of beer on the wall
1 bottle of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
No more bottles of beer on the wall
```

Answer (score 0):

Your interface may have just cut the top off of the outputs or maybe you did not scroll up. The above code works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Its actually is outputting the values you expected, the most likely problem is your output window is cutting the output towards to the top.

The following output on NetBeans:

```
run:
99 bottles of beer on the wall
99 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
98 bottles of beer on the wall
98 bottles of beer on the wall
98 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
97 bottles of beer on the wall
97 bottles of beer on the wall
97 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
96 bottles of beer on the wall
96 bottles of beer on the wall
96 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
95 bottles of beer on the wall
95 bottles of beer on the wall
95 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
94 bottles of beer on the wall
94 bottles of beer on the wall
94 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
93 bottles of beer on the wall
93 bottles of beer on the wall
93 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
92 bottles of beer on the wall
92 bottles of beer on the wall
92 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
91 bottles of beer on the wall
91 bottles of beer on the wall
91 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
90 bottles of beer on the wall
90 bottles of beer on the wall
90 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
89 bottles of beer on the wall
89 bottles of beer on the wall
89 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
88 bottles of beer on the wall
88 bottles of beer on the wall
88 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
87 bottles of beer on the wall
87 bottles of beer on the wall
87 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
86 bottles of beer on the wall
86 bottles of beer on the wall
86 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
85 bottles of beer on the wall
85 bottles of beer on the wall
85 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
84 bottles of beer on the wall
84 bottles of beer on the wall
84 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
83 bottles of beer on the wall
83 bottles of beer on the wall
83 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
82 bottles of beer on the wall
82 bottles of beer on the wall
82 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
81 bottles of beer on the wall
81 bottles of beer on the wall
81 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
80 bottles of beer on the wall
80 bottles of beer on the wall
80 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
79 bottles of beer on the wall
79 bottles of beer on the wall
79 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
78 bottles of beer on the wall
78 bottles of beer on the wall
78 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
77 bottles of beer on the wall
77 bottles of beer on the wall
77 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
76 bottles of beer on the wall
76 bottles of beer on the wall
76 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
75 bottles of beer on the wall
75 bottles of beer on the wall
75 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
74 bottles of beer on the wall
74 bottles of beer on the wall
74 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
73 bottles of beer on the wall
73 bottles of beer on the wall
73 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
72 bottles of beer on the wall
72 bottles of beer on the wall
72 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
71 bottles of beer on the wall
71 bottles of beer on the wall
71 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
70 bottles of beer on the wall
70 bottles of beer on the wall
70 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
69 bottles of beer on the wall
69 bottles of beer on the wall
69 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
68 bottles of beer on the wall
68 bottles of beer on the wall
68 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
67 bottles of beer on the wall
67 bottles of beer on the wall
67 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
66 bottles of beer on the wall
66 bottles of beer on the wall
66 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
65 bottles of beer on the wall
65 bottles of beer on the wall
65 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
64 bottles of beer on the wall
64 bottles of beer on the wall
64 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
63 bottles of beer on the wall
63 bottles of beer on the wall
63 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
62 bottles of beer on the wall
62 bottles of beer on the wall
62 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
61 bottles of beer on the wall
61 bottles of beer on the wall
61 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
60 bottles of beer on the wall
60 bottles of beer on the wall
60 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
59 bottles of beer on the wall
59 bottles of beer on the wall
59 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
58 bottles of beer on the wall
58 bottles of beer on the wall
58 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
57 bottles of beer on the wall
57 bottles of beer on the wall
57 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
56 bottles of beer on the wall
56 bottles of beer on the wall
56 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
55 bottles of beer on the wall
55 bottles of beer on the wall
55 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
54 bottles of beer on the wall
54 bottles of beer on the wall
54 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
53 bottles of beer on the wall
53 bottles of beer on the wall
53 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
52 bottles of beer on the wall
52 bottles of beer on the wall
52 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
51 bottles of beer on the wall
51 bottles of beer on the wall
51 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
50 bottles of beer on the wall
50 bottles of beer on the wall
50 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
49 bottles of beer on the wall
49 bottles of beer on the wall
49 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
48 bottles of beer on the wall
48 bottles of beer on the wall
48 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
47 bottles of beer on the wall
47 bottles of beer on the wall
47 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
46 bottles of beer on the wall
46 bottles of beer on the wall
46 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
45 bottles of beer on the wall
45 bottles of beer on the wall
45 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
44 bottles of beer on the wall
44 bottles of beer on the wall
44 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
43 bottles of beer on the wall
43 bottles of beer on the wall
43 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
42 bottles of beer on the wall
42 bottles of beer on the wall
42 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
41 bottles of beer on the wall
41 bottles of beer on the wall
41 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
40 bottles of beer on the wall
40 bottles of beer on the wall
40 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
39 bottles of beer on the wall
39 bottles of beer on the wall
39 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
38 bottles of beer on the wall
38 bottles of beer on the wall
38 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
37 bottles of beer on the wall
37 bottles of beer on the wall
37 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
36 bottles of beer on the wall
36 bottles of beer on the wall
36 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
35 bottles of beer on the wall
35 bottles of beer on the wall
35 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
34 bottles of beer on the wall
34 bottles of beer on the wall
34 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
33 bottles of beer on the wall
33 bottles of beer on the wall
33 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
32 bottles of beer on the wall
32 bottles of beer on the wall
32 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
31 bottles of beer on the wall
31 bottles of beer on the wall
31 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
30 bottles of beer on the wall
30 bottles of beer on the wall
30 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
29 bottles of beer on the wall
29 bottles of beer on the wall
29 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
28 bottles of beer on the wall
28 bottles of beer on the wall
28 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
27 bottles of beer on the wall
27 bottles of beer on the wall
27 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
26 bottles of beer on the wall
26 bottles of beer on the wall
26 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
25 bottles of beer on the wall
25 bottles of beer on the wall
25 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
24 bottles of beer on the wall
24 bottles of beer on the wall
24 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
23 bottles of beer on the wall
23 bottles of beer on the wall
23 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
22 bottles of beer on the wall
22 bottles of beer on the wall
22 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
21 bottles of beer on the wall
21 bottles of beer on the wall
21 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
20 bottles of beer on the wall
20 bottles of beer on the wall
20 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
19 bottles of beer on the wall
19 bottles of beer on the wall
19 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
18 bottles of beer on the wall
18 bottles of beer on the wall
18 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
17 bottles of beer on the wall
17 bottles of beer on the wall
17 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
16 bottles of beer on the wall
16 bottles of beer on the wall
16 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
15 bottles of beer on the wall
15 bottles of beer on the wall
15 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
14 bottles of beer on the wall
14 bottles of beer on the wall
14 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
13 bottles of beer on the wall
13 bottles of beer on the wall
13 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
12 bottles of beer on the wall
12 bottles of beer on the wall
12 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
11 bottles of beer on the wall
11 bottles of beer on the wall
11 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
10 bottles of beer on the wall
10 bottles of beer on the wall
10 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
9 bottles of beer on the wall
9 bottles of beer on the wall
9 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
8 bottles of beer on the wall
8 bottles of beer on the wall
8 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
7 bottles of beer on the wall
7 bottles of beer on the wall
7 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
6 bottles of beer on the wall
6 bottles of beer on the wall
6 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
5 bottles of beer on the wall
5 bottles of beer on the wall
5 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
4 bottles of beer on the wall
4 bottles of beer on the wall
4 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
3 bottles of beer on the wall
3 bottles of beer on the wall
3 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
2 bottles of beer on the wall
2 bottles of beer on the wall
2 bottles of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.
1 bottles of beer on the wall
1 bottle of beer on the wall
1 bottle of beer Take one down
    .
Pass it around.No more bottles of beer on the wall
```

To try and check for would be change `while (beerNum > 0)` to something like `while (beerNum > 50)` so that it doesn't produce so much output.

Answer (score 0):

You're right to be confused as the code does in fact output "99 bottles of beer... and so on."

Answer (score 0):

It might be happening because your output console buffer in your IDE is reached so only the output within the console limit is shown.

If you are using eclipse then
1. Go to eclipse preference 
2. Search console 
3. Remove the check "Limit console output"

else

Just change beerNum to some lesser value (i.e less than 50) and you will see complete output